# Using user variable to show data between dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, date-range

I want to show all the data between given dates. date for which no data is found i want to show null for all the columns

Table Schema

```
TimeEntry(id: integer, project_id: integer, user_id: integer, hours: float, comments: string, spent_on: date)
```

What i tried so far,

```
set @num = -1;
SELECT DATE_ADD(  '2009-01-01', INTERVAL @num := @num +1
DAY ) AS date_sequence, time_entries.id
FROM time_entries
WHERE user_id =55
HAVING DATE_ADD(  '2009-01-01', INTERVAL @num DAY ) <=  '2012-01-01'
```

It gives following output

```
date_sequence id
2009-01-01  46
2009-01-02  50
2009-01-03  55
2009-01-04  01
2009-01-05  02
2009-01-06  24
2009-01-07  57
2009-01-08  59
2009-01-09  74
2009-01-10  78
```

Expected output is

```
date_sequence id
2009-01-01  NULL
2009-01-02  NULL
2009-01-03  NULL
2009-01-04  NULL
2009-01-05  NULL
2009-01-06  NULL
2009-01-07  NULL
2009-01-08  NULL
2009-01-09  74
2009-01-10  78
```

because id exists only for 09 and 10

How to match the dates with other fields?

Hints/Comments?

Rails based solution would be also be useful.

**EDIT:**

what i tried in rails so far

```
def create_dates(from_time,till_time)
  dates = []
  date_from = from_time.to_time
  while date_from <= till_time.to_time && periods.length <= 100          
      dates << "#{date_from.to_date}"
      date_from = date_from + 1.day
  end
dates
```

end

It returns me the dates between given period. but i cant get to match my data with these dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set @num = -1;
select t1.date_sequence, count(t2.id) from
 (SELECT DATE_ADD(  '2009-01-01', INTERVAL @num := @num +1 DAY ) AS date_sequence
  FROM time_entries HAVING DATE_ADD(  '2009-01-01', INTERVAL @num + 1 DAY ) <=  '2012-01-01') as t1
left outer join time_entries as t2 on t1.date_sequence = t2.spent_on
group by t1.date_sequence
order by t1.date_sequence;
```

Comment: thnx. i got what i was missing. i needed to create a view of dates and then left join this with time_entries table. also what do you think would be more efficient?(a) i use user_variables in sql query, (b) use a lookup table(holding dates), or i fill the dates on rails side using normal query.

Comment: user_variables in sql query should be the fastest. I am up voting your question. Thanks. Good luck.

Comment: well i am not sure that user_variables are fastest of the three options. thnx for your solution though. i will check it. cheers!

Comment: FYI: using extra table would be faster in this case. for 100 records avg time with using extra/look-up table is  0.0395 sec while with user variables, avg time for 100 records is 0.0420 sec. but i will stick to user variables. as for me this much diff is ok. thnx again.